# Which Python template engine is safe to be used by untrusted users?

Tags: python, security, templates, template-engine, code-injection

I'm looking for a good standalone Python template engine that is safe, against code injecting, to be used in an application that allows untrusted users to write and edit templates. Could someone recommend such an engine?

Comment: You maybe can have a look to jinja http://jinja.pocoo.org/

Comment: Giving untrusted users access to the site's templates sounds scary.

Comment: Part of this depends on what variables/namespaces you are including/making available in your view context that you feed to the templates. For example it would be dangerous if you make something like `os` available (either directly or implicitly accessible via some other module or variable that imports it)

Comment: @ayanami, I was looking for a safe template engine for a component of my Django project, where staff would be able to write email templates, using placeholders for full names, email addresses, relevant info for their customer, etc. There is a use for user-written templates; I would not want some crafty person to exploit my site through the template engine.

Answer (score 0):

starcom referenced jinja.

The [jinja website](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) says, under "features":

> Sandboxed execution mode. Every aspect of the template execution is
>   monitored and explicitly whitelisted or blacklisted, whatever is
>   preferred. This makes it possible to execute untrusted templates.

Comment: _The sandbox alone is not a solution for perfect security. Keep these things in mind when using the sandbox_